# Angular - Multi step form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one issue with angular js.

My problem is:
I have a multi step form with inputs, also I have a select field and by selected value I show button with I can add another input fields.I use    **ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid"**, but the problems is he catch all others inputs in other form steps.How to validate.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english!

app.js

```
 var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', []).config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%').endSymbol('%>');
});

validationApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.log = function () {
        console.log($scope.userForm);
    };
    /*
     * If is selected partnership will show button for adding partners.
     */
    $(".category").click(function () {
        var value = $(".category option:selected").val();
        var token = $('.csrf').val();
        var solo = 1;
        var partnership = 2;

        if (value == solo || value == '') {
            $('.partner-button').hide();
            $('.inputs').remove();
        } else if (value == partnership) {
            $('.partner-button').show();
            //$(".input_fields_wrap").append(fields);
            //$compile(fields)($scope);
        }
    });

    /*
     * Adding fields for partner.
     */

    var count = 0;
    $('.add_field_button').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var input = $("<div class=\"inputs\">" +
            "<input type=\"text\" ng-model=\"partnerName" + count + "\" name=\"partners[" + count + "][name]\" placeholder=\"Наименование на партньор\" required/>" +
            "<p ng-show=\"userForm['partners[" + count + "][name]'].$error.required\" class=\"errors\">Наименованието на партньора е задалжително</p>" +
            "<input type=\"text\" ng-model=\"partnerUrn" + count + "\" name=\"partners[" + count + "][urn]\" placeholder=\"БУЛСТАТ (ЕИК) на партньора\" required>" +
            "<p ng-show=\"userForm['partners[" + count + "][urn]'].$error.required\" class=\"errors\">Полето БУЛСТАТ е задалжително</p>" +
            "<br><a href=\"#\" class=\"font remove_field\">Премахни</a>" +
            "</div>");
        count++;
        $(".input_fields_wrap").append(input);
        $compile(input)($scope);


    });

    $('.input_fields_wrap').on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        count--;
    });
});
```

HTML Form First Step

```
<fieldset>
<h2 class="fs-title">ПРОВЕРКА НА КАНДИДАТ</h2>

<div class="application-type">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Тип на кандидатстване: </h2>
    <select
            name="category"
            class="category"
            ng-model="category"
            required
            >
        <option value="">Изберете тип на кандидатстване</option>
        <option value="1">Самостоятелно</option>
        <option value="2">В партньорство</option>
    </select>

    <p ng-show="userForm.category.$error.required" class="errors">Моля изберете тип на кандидатстване</p>
</div>
<p>
    <input type="text"
           name="urn"
           placeholder="БУЛСТАТ(ЕИК)"
           ng-model="urn"
           ng-minlength="9"
           ng-maxlength="13"
           required
           ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.urn.$invalid && !userForm.urn.$pristine }"/>

<p ng-show="userForm.urn.$error.required" class="errors">Полето БУЛСТАТ е задалжително</p>

<p ng-show="userForm.urn.$error.minlength" class="errors">Невалиден БУЛСТАТ</p>

<p ng-show="userForm.urn.$error.maxlength" class="errors">Невалиден БУЛСТАТ</p>
</p>



<div class="input_fields_wrap"></div>
<button class="partner-button action-button add_field_button">Добави партньор</button>

<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" value="Напред"/>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfUWRkTAAAAABPcgj4QN-LZzrmv4ZvGDqNGInxN"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ngForm](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) which is *"an alias"* (if you don't take into consideration that [ng-submit doesn't work with ng-form](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2513)) of [form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) in order to group the steps together.

This way each **ngForm** with a defined name, much like **form**, will get its own form controller thus allowing you to use `ng-disabled="firstStep.$invalid"`, `ng-disabled="secondStep.$invalid"` etc.